# iOS deployment failed through Delphi Tokyo 10.2 due to provisioningProfile dictionary error

Tags: ios, delphi, deployment, compiler-errors

I have an issue which seems similar to the question here:

[Xcode 9 distribution build fails because format of exportOptions.plist has changed in new release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45748140/xcode-9-distribution-build-fails-because-format-of-exportoptions-plist-has-chang)

However, my situation differs because my app is being built through Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, not XCode, so I cannot use the recommended fix. I have provisioning profiles set up for deployment to the app store, and they worked a month ago. I had to make some changes for IPv6 compatibility which did not impact project settings in any way, and now deployment is failing with the following log output:

```
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 2017-10-30 15:13:52.911 xcodebuild[3123:464547] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/d_/1k9k2tf93qn6mxc0v0g4y0440000gn/T/appName_2017-10-30_15-13-52.910.xcdistributionlogs'.
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 2017-10-30 15:13:53.584 xcodebuild[3123:464547] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7fbeca5ddf10>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepErrorDomain Code=0 "Locating signing assets failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Locating signing assets failed., IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepUnderlyingErrors=(
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776     "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 \"\"appName.app\" requires a provisioning profile.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=\"appName.app\" requires a provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the \"provisioningProfiles\" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}"
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 )}
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 error: exportArchive: "appName.app" requires a provisioning profile.
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""appName.app" requires a provisioning profile." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription="appName.app" requires a provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 ** EXPORT FAILED **
```

I have replaced the actual app name with 'appName' for security purposes. We have been trying to deploy our app to the Apple App Store for over a month. Does anyone have any insight as to how we can address this issue?

Comment: What version of Delphi? Do you have this patch installed? http://codecentral.embarcadero.com/Item/30805

Comment: Thank you, @DaveNottage. Of course, yet another Embarcadero-Apple compatibility patch. Appears to have solved the problem. If you post it as an answer, rather than a comment, I can upvote it.

Comment: "Of course, yet another Embarcadero-Apple compatibility patch". Yes, if Apple did not make any changes to their product, there would be no need for Embarcadero (or anyone else who supports iOS and macOS) to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please install this patch:

http://codecentral.embarcadero.com/Item/30805

Which accounts for changes in Xcode 9