# React Native IOS: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format on xcode9

Tags: ios, react-native, export, xcode9, ipa

When i am exporting ipa file with xcode9. (react native project)
i got this error

> The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

and the log file:

```
2017-11-20 10:09:41 +0000  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
2017-11-20 10:09:41 +0000  : incompatible library version - /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle (fatal)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/gulliver/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/ext.rb:7:in `<module:Ext>'
    from /Users/gulliver/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/ext.rb:6:in `<module:JSON>'
    from /Users/gulliver/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/ext.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/gulliver/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json.rb:59:in `<module:JSON>'
    from /Users/gulliver/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json.rb:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:18:in `<main>'
```

Please help!!!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 9 distribution build fails because format of exportOptions.plist has changed in new release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45748140/xcode-9-distribution-build-fails-because-format-of-exportoptions-plist-has-chang)

Comment: Thanks for your help!. But my problem not to be the same as. i just downgrade my xcode to 8 and well done. btw, thanks!

Comment: @hoang.vx, did you ever resolve this?